# Cannot inject EntityManager in persistence layer class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate 4.1 - Spring 4 - Jpa 2 - Jersey

I'm facing a problem since a couple of days. 
Whenever I try to inject an EntityManager in my class, it ends up with null pointer exception. 
Below is the class where i'm calling the entity manager

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Student")
private EntityManager em;
/**
 * This method returns all the items
 * @return List of all items
 */
@Transactional
public List<Item> getAllItems() {
    //EntityManager em =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Student").createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Item.getAllItems");
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
         list =  query.getResultList();
    }finally{
       em.close(); 
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is my ApplicationContext.xml file :

```
 ==============================================================================================================
                                               DATASOURCE
      ==============================================================================================================   -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>

<!-- ==============================================================================================================
                                               ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY
      ==============================================================================================================   -->
 <bean id="emf"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Student" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">static</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation">create-tables</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode">database</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- ==============================================================================================================
                                               TRANSACTION MANAGER
      ==============================================================================================================   -->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
```

Right now, I'm creating an entity manager for each of my method and this might not be the best way to handle it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1

New config

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.service" /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.repository" />
```

```
<bean id="emf"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Student" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">static</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation">create-tables</prop>
            <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode">database</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>


<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
       class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: How are you creating the class that contains the `EntityManager`?

Comment: I'm using the Repository annotation on it, that's it. Hope i'm answering your question @Reimeus

Comment: yes but is Spring handling the creation of the class?

Comment: @Reimeus nop it is not

Comment: then that is the problem :)

Comment: Haha knew you would say that, It's my first time using all of this and it quite complex in the beginning. I should add this class using the entityManager to my ApplicationContext file as a bean and that should be it right ? @Reimeus

Answer (score 0):

As @Reimeus said, you need to configurate Spring to take care about repository class.

One way is telling Spring where and which annotated class should scan for. There are a lot of tutorials examples that shows how to do it (for example check the `context:component-scan` tag in the *Spring Configuration* section of [this tutorial](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jpa-hibernate-example)). Next I show you one template to add in your ApplicationContext file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<full_package_name_where_is_your_Repository_class>">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>
```

To get it work set the correct `base-package` value, add the namespace `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` and the schema location `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` too.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I did  add the component scan to my applicationContext file. Added the scanning for my repository & service package but i'm still getting a null pointer exception when I inject my EM via @PersistenceContext.

Comment: Edit you question with you actual configuration. Check that you have `<context:annotation-config />`